# Cplex is it possible to write objective function like this

Tags: cplex, nonlinear-optimization, objective-function

I have a 2d matrix of scores as parameters.
I have nxm variables x[i,j], those variables can assume integer values in a predetermined range.
I need to maximize something like this:
[desidered objective function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvdwr.png)

Where scores is the matrix.
Is it possible to define such a objective function?

Comment: See the guide below. [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) / [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) / [how-to-create-minimal-reproducible-code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

2 options as said in  [How to use a decision variable as an index with CPLEX](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/indexisadecisionvariable.mod) part of [HOW TO WITH OPL CPLEX](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/)?

With CPOptimizer in CPLEX

```
using CP;
range r=1..5;
float value[r]=[2,3,4.5,1,0];
dvar int i in 1..5;
maximize value[i];
subject to
{
}
execute
{
writeln("i=",i);
}
```

or with CPLEX MIP

```
range r=1..5;

float value[r]=[2,3,4.5,1,0];
dvar int i in 1..5;

maximize sum(k in r) value[k]*(k==i);
subject to
{

}

execute
{
writeln("i=",i);
}
```

and with your objective that gives

```
using CP;

int N=4;
int M=5;

range R=1..10;

int scores[i in R][j in R]=i*j;

dvar int x[0..N+1][0..M] in R;

maximize sum(i in 0..N,j in 0..M) scores[x[i,j],x[i+1,j]];

subject to
{
  
}
```